# Extract Locoscript data

Tags: data-extraction, file-conversion

I need to extract the data from Locoscript files.I have a computer running Windows XP so I can read the data. Can you help? Thanks.

I have tried opening in WordPad and Excel. I can read the text, but there are too many extra characters and no formatting. I have a lot of data to extract so it is impractical to delete all of the additional characters. The Text Import Wizard doesn't seem to help.

Answer (score 0):

At the time of writing, it is still possible to buy a downloadable copy of LocoLink for Windows on eBay. This is a 16-bit PC application that can convert LocoScript documents to a variety of 1990s formats such as RTF, Word 5.0/6.0 or WordPerfect 6.0.

(In your query, you use the word 'Data'. If you are using this to mean LocoFile databases rather than LocoScript documents, you're in luck: LocoLink can convert databases to CSV, dBase or FoxPro formats).

Since LocoLink for Windows is a 16-bit application, you will need a 16-bit or 32-bit version of Windows to run it. Your copy of Windows XP is most likely to be 32-bit, so that should not present a problem.

Alternatively, if you can obtain a copy of LocoScript PC, that would also be able to open the documents and export them in WordPerfect format.